# Assigning a variable with zero value if not existing in loaded file (Octave)

Tags: matrix, octave, mat

The Case1.Mat file contains
X   Y  Z
2   6  3
3   7   4
4   8   6

### 5   9   8

```
load(Case1.Mat); # loaded a Case1.Mat file in Octave
label=[{X;Y;Z;V}]; # I have a matrix of predefined variables
Nrow=numel(label);
ResMat=ones(Nrow,1);
for k=1:Nrow;
ResMat(k,1)=max(label{k,1});
End
```

---

I have just shown the example of simplification of my problem, however in my case the Mat file contains >300 Variables, and for each case the number of variables changes. Hence I have defined a label matrix with all the variables. In the above example the variable ‘V’ is not in the .mat file and hence it results in an error and execution stops.
I am trying to compute the maximum of each variable(column). My question is, whenever, I encounter a situation where, the defined variable in ‘labels’ is not in the loaded .Mat file then that variable value (‘V’ in this case) should be assigned as zero (double) so that my Nrow should be ‘4’ and my ‘ResMat’ should look like this ResMat=[5;9;8;0]
I am new to this programming environment so pardon the way I have put the question.

After reply
Case1_lg.MAT
error: 'oflv3' undefined near line 8 column 33

### error: called from procsMax3 at line 8 column 6

```
# Constantes (my actual code)
for i=1;
for j={'lg'};
filename = strcat("Case",sprintf("%d",i),"_",j{},".MAT");
load(filename);
display(filename);
Ncol=1;
label=[{vBrfrda;vBrfrdb;vBrfrdc;oflv3}];
if ~isfield(label, 'V')
    data.V = 0;
endif
Nrow=numel(label);
ResMat=ones(Nrow,Ncol);
for k=1:Nrow;
ResMat(k,i)=max(label{k,i});
end
end
end
```

in the above case oflv3 is not in the .Mat file

Comment: The Case1.Mat file contains
X  =[{2;3;4;5}];
Y  =[{6;7;8;9}];
Z=[{3;4;6;8}];
sorry it was not clear earlier

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exist` to check for the existence of a variable and if that variable isn't defined, assign a default value

```
if ~exist('V', 'var')
    V = 0;
end
```

A better approach though is to specify an output to `load` so that all variables are assigned as fields in a `struct` so you don't have to worry about overwriting variables that may be in the user's workspace already or a host of other possible issues. In this case, you could use `isfield` to check if `V` is present in the file and replace with a default value if needed

```
data = load(filename);

if ~isfield(data, 'V')
    data.V = 0;
end
```

Comment: Thanks Suever, that was quite quick reply. I appreciate your response. further I am getting the following error. Case1_lg.MAT
error: 'oflv3' undefined near line 8 column 33
error: called from procsMax3 at line 8 column 6
# Constantes
for i=1;
for j={'lg'};
filename = strcat("Case",sprintf("%d",i),"_",j{},".MAT");
load(filename);
display(filename);
Ncol=1;
label=[{vBrfrda;vBrfrdb;vBrfrdc;oflv3}];
if ~isfield(label, 'V')
    data.V = 0;
endif
Nrow=numel(label);
ResMat=ones(Nrow,Ncol);
for k=1:Nrow;
ResMat(k,i)=max(label{k,i});
end
end
end ( oflv3 is not in the MAT file)

Comment: @MunjiKiran You clearly have a missing variable named `oflv3`. You'll have to check for *each* variable that you need the way that I showed in my answer