# Clearing a specific global variable in octave

Tags: matlab, variables, octave, global

I am trying to load the variables from a multiple .mat files  using 'who' function and saving it in a variable 'A'. I am using a for loop for that. When I finish loading the first file and start loading the second file then 'A' shows variables in first .mat file as well. The problem is the function 'who' saves the variables as it is for multiple loops and I want to clear the 'who' after each loop. How can I do this. There is any way to clear a specific global variable.

```
for i=1:10; (10 mat files)
clear A;
clear who;
A=who; (all the variables in each mat file saved in A)
max(A(1,1); (finding max of variable A(1,1))
end
```

from the above code, if each .mat file has 5 variables then in the second loop the 'who' has 10 variables. the who is not cleared.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do because [`who`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Status-of-Variables.html#index-who) (with no input arguments) returns a list of all variables in the current workspace not the variables within a file. For it to return a list of variables within a file you'd need to do something like:

```
vars = who('-file', filenames{i});
```

That being said, it looks like you actually want to load the variable `A` from all mat files that you've saved and find the maximum value of `A` across these files.

The better way to approach this is to specify an output to `load` which will load the data into a `struct` where each variable is stored as a separate field in the struct. You can also specify an additional input to `load` to specify that you'd only like to load variable `A` (in case there are other variables). You can then load each matfile into a separate `struct` and do your comparison

```
for k = 1:numel(filenames)
    % Load variable A from this file into a struct
    data(k) = load(filenames{k}, 'A');
end

% Now find the maximum value of A
maxA = max([data.A]);
```

Comment: it's a pity that you already gave almost the same advice (use load with return value) some days ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709118/assigning-a-variable-with-zero-value-if-not-existing-in-loaded-file-octave

Comment: @Andy Why is that a pity? It's a different problem with a similar solution. Oh wait I see, it's the same user.... I guess they didn't take the advice to heart